# Sequence result on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I tried to code a program using **Fibonacci** sequence with `JFrame`. but, the result just showed the end of looping result like "8,"

How can I show the entire sequence result like this? => 0,1,1,2,3,5,8

```
public class Ree extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Ree() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void fibonacci() {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        int x = Integer.parseInt(n_data.getText());

        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            String q = Integer.toString(a);
            output.setText(q + ", ");
            a = a + b;
            b = a - b;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
output.setText(q + ", ");
```

Should be something like:

```
output.append(q + ", ");
```

> `.append` would only apply to `JTextArea` - MadProgrammer

Oh my bad. In that case, use..

```
output.setText(output.getText() + q + ", ");
```

Comment: There was error come out "cannot find symbol Symbol: method append(String) Location: variable jTextField1 of type jTextField", when i try with your suggestion. Can you point me in some direction?

Comment: @studentJ `.append` would only apply to `JTextArea`